# Borrar ficheros con más antigüedad de 7 días en bash

Tags: shell

Estoy programando un script que haga una limpieza de logs teniendo en cuenta que su antigüedad sea mayor a 7 días.

El código que tengo ahora mismo, para probar, solo debe mover a una carpeta de prueba (quiero asegurarme de que solo coge ficheros con más de 7 días antes de pasar al `rm`):

```sh
find /ruta_equipo/log/*.log -mtime +7 -type f -exec mv /ruta_equipo/log/prueba/ {}\;
```

El error que me arroja ahora mismo es:

`find: missing argument to '-exec'`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Después de leerme la documentación de `find` y probar varios parámetros, he encontrado la solución.

Cuando se utiliza este comando, las llaves del final `{}` sustituye a la línea en cuestión de ese instante. Por lo tanto, solo hay que usarlo como ruta de origen en el comando `mv`:

```
find /ruta_equipo/log/*.log -mtime +7 -type f -exec mv '{}' /ruta_equipo/log/prueba/ \;
```

Comment: Buenas. Si has encontrado la solución a tu problema, recuerda marcar esta respuesta como válida, aunque sea tuya, para que así otros sepan que está resuelto. Un saludo.

Comment: Buenas @Emerita. El problema es que no me deja marcar una respuesta mía como válida hasta dos días después.

Comment: Ohh, pues anda pendiente entonces, para que no se te pase. Así mantenemos esto limpio y ordenado.