# Script en Linux que borre archivos mayores de 500 MB y tengan más de 3 días

Tags: linux, script, unix, terminal

Mi duda es que instrucción se debe agregar para poder filtrar los archivos mayores de 500 MB en una carpeta.

Me he basado en esta [pregunta](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/248931/borrar-ficheros-con-m%C3%A1s-antig%C3%BCedad-de-7-d%C3%ADas-en-bash) y en esta [otra](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/374394/eliminar-archivos-con-mas-de-x-d%C3%ADas-en-mi-servidor) para poder hacer el borrado de archivos de x días de antigüedad, pero no he encontrado la instrucción para filtrar por tamaño de archivo.

```
 find /data -type f -mtime +3 -size +500M -exec rm {} \;
```

Comment: sería bueno que mostraras el comando que tienes actualmente en base a esos dos comandos que ya encontraste

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Intenta con:

```
$ find <folder> -type f -size +500 -mtime +3
```

Observa si son los archivos que quieres, y, en caso de que sean, puedes utilizar al buen `xargs`, o el argumento `-delete` para hacerlo todo al vuelo.

```
$ find <folder> -type f -size +500M -mtime +3 | xargs rm
$ find <folder> -type f -size +500M -mtime +3 -delete
```

Esto se da gracias a que `-mtime [+|-]N` opera como días pues es tomado como `N por 24 horas` (esto viene en `find(1)`).

Sólo que toma en cuenta que **no en todos los sistemas de archivo podremos encontrar la fecha de creación**.

Las fechas que te proporcina `find` son las usuales: modificación (la última vez que su contenido fue modificado), cambio (se refiere a cuando se cambiaron los metadatos como los permisos, etc), acceso (se refiere a la lectura de este archivo).

Por esto, la respuesta de usar `-mtime` se refiera a la última vez que fueron modificados, más no creados.

Por ejemplo, si creamos un archivo y le alteramos las fechas con:

```
$ touch -md "2 days ago" archivo
$ touch -ad "6 days ago" archivo
```

Y luego le aplicas `stat`, obtienes algo como:

```
$ stat archivo
  File: 'archivo'
  Size: 0               Blocks: 0          IO Block: 512    regular empty file
Device: 2h/2d   Inode: 157907461934774767  Links: 1
Access: (0644/-rw-r--r--)  Uid: ( 1000/    cuau)   Gid: ( 1000/    cuau)
Access: 2020-10-13 05:53:41.958891200 -0500
Modify: 2020-10-17 05:53:14.582211900 -0500
Change: 2020-10-19 05:53:41.959260700 -0500
 Birth: -
```

Donde puedes ver el truco durante las fechas de modificación y acceso. Lo cual difiere de su fecha de creación (que no viene presente). También se le podría cambiar la fecha de modificación (*change*) con unos trucos más.

Answer (score 2):

Si has usado esas preguntas como base, estas en el camino correcto.
Pero veo que en ninguna de las 2, han usado la instruccion -size.

```
find / -type f -and -size +100M
```

`-type f` para indicar que deseamos restringir nuestra búsqueda a archivos regulares únicamente.
Además de `M`, la opción `-size` también acepta `c` (bytes), `k` (kilobytes), y `G` (gigabytes)

Comment: Gracias por tu respuesta.
¿Entonces podría quedar algo así?
find /data -type f -mtime +3 -size +500M -exec rm {} \;

Comment: Aproximadamente, pero has pruebas primero, y genera casos donde pueda fallar.

Comment: find /data -type f -mtime +3 -size +500M -delete